# Socket.IO - Creating rooms through a Mysql chat_id

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io, sequelize.js

I am building a web chat application using express, socket.io, node.js, sequelize and mysql. When a user creates a chatroom, the MySQL table gets populated with a chat_id and chat_name, if they join a room the chat_id is retrieved. The user is taken to the chatroom endpoint /chat/3, 3 depicting the selected chat_id. I cannot figure out how to create a room that uses a chat_id from the DB, and only allows communication between members of the same chat.

My socket server setup is

```
const socket = require('socket.io');
const { initAllSockets } = require('./controllers/websockets');

const SOCKET_PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;

function initSocketServer(server) {
  const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
      // allowing all urls to access
      origin: '*'
    }
  });
  io.on('connection', socket => {
    initAllSockets(socket, io);
  });
  server.listen(SOCKET_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Socket server listening on PORT: ${SOCKET_PORT}`);
  });
}

module.exports = { initSocketServer };
```

Websockets Message controller

```
const { Message } = require('../../models/Message');

function initMessagesSocket(socket, io) {
  socket.on('newMessage', async msg => {
    try {
      const createMessage = await Message.create(msg);
      socket.broadcast.emit('message', createMessage.get({ plain: true }));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    console.log('message', msg);
  });
}
```

Chat to Message controller - where I'm having trouble

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:4001');

const getId = async obj => {
  const chatroomName = obj.id;
  console.log(chatroomName);
  const sendToChatRoom = await fetch('/api/chatMessage', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ chatroomName }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const response = await sendToChatRoom.json();
  if (response) {    
    console.log(response);
    document.location.replace(`/chat/${response}`);
    console.log(response);
  }
};
```

Index of controllers

```
// TODO: import all functionality for sockets
const { initMessagesSocket } = require('./messages');
const { initChatSocket } = require('./chats');

function initAllSockets(socket, io) {
  initMessagesSocket(socket, io);
  initChatSocket(socket, io);
}

module.exports = { initAllSockets };
```

Chat Model using sequelize

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../config/connection.js');

class Chat extends Model {}

Chat.init(
  //TODO: Define the model for chats
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    chat_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      unique: true
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: 'Chat'
  }
);

module.exports = { Chat };
```